# Use for-loop and if function to create a new vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I want to do the following operation with the code: I want to get a sample of n = 30 out of a given normal distribution and calculate the mean of each sample. (until this step my function works without any problem). After that I want to create a new vector with yes or no , dependent on if the mean is in a certain range or not. Sadly the code does notconduct this step. I always get a vector with 13 elements,but there should be 500. What is the problem? Where is my mistake?

```
o = 13
u = 7
d = c()
for (i in 1:500){
  i = rnorm(30,mean = 10,sd = 6.04)
  i = mean(i)
  if (i <= o & i >=u) {
    d[i]=("Yes")
  } else {
    d[i]=("No")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid changing the value of your iterator (`i`) within your loop. In your case, your `i` is becoming a non-integer value.  When you try to index your `d` vector, it takes the integer portion of `i`.

Consider what happens when I have a vector

```
x <- 1:4
```

and I take the `pi` index of it.

```
x[pi]
# [1] 3
```

Your code should look more like this:

```
o = 13
u = 7

d = c()

for (i in 1:500){
  sample_i = rnorm(30, mean = 10, sd = 6.04)
  mean_i = mean(sample_i)
  if (mean_i <= o & mean_i >=u) {
    d[i]=("Yes")
  } else {
    d[i]=("No")
  }
}
```

If you would like to improve your code some, here are some suggestions:

First, avoid "growing" your results.  This has performance implications.  It is better to decide how long your result (`d`) should be and set it to that length to begin with.

Next, try not to hard code the number of iterations into your loop.  Get familiar with `seq_along` and `seq_len` and use them to count iterations for you.

```
o = 13
u = 7

d = numeric(500)    #  I made a change here

for (i in seq_along(d)){  # And I made a change here
  sample_i = rnorm(30, mean = 10, sd = 6.04)
  mean_i = mean(sample_i)
  if (mean_i <= o & mean_i >=u) {
    d[i]=("Yes")
  } else {
    d[i]=("No")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. This helps a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Re-assigning i looks like a bad idea to me.

Are you sure you want to do this in a for loop? If not, a vectorised solution with crossing (tidyverse - nice explanations at varianceexplained.org ) should work pretty nicely, I think?

```r
o = 13
u = 7

crossing(trial = 1:500,
         rounds = 1:30)%>%
  mutate(num = rnorm(n(), mean = 10,  sd = 6.04))%>%
  group_by(trial)%>%
  summarise(mean = mean(num))%>%
  mutate(d = case_when(mean <= o & mean >= u ~ "Yes",
                       TRUE ~ "No"))%>%
  count(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at this possibility and try to understand it.